# simple php captcha contact form

Tags: php, html

i am trying to create simple contact form with captcha in php. However it turns out implementing captcha is out of my league.

I found a simple answer on stackoverflow opn similar problem which pushed me 1 step closer to the end, but again i got stuck.

So i need a contact form that only check if text is entered and if correct captcha is answered, email is not mandatory.

```html
</br>

<?php
    $a=rand(2,9);
    $b=rand(2,9);
    $c=$a+$b;


 if (isset($_POST['contact_text']) && isset($_POST['contact_email']) ) {
  $contact_text = $_POST['contact_text'];
  $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
  $recaptcha = $_POST['recaptcha'];
  
  $info = 'Pranešimas apie korupciją: ';
  $sender = 'Atsiuntė: ';
   
  if (!empty($contact_text) && ($recaptcha == $c ))  {
    
  echo $recaptcha;
  
  $to = 'muksinovas@gmail.com';
  $subject = 'Korupcija';
  $body = $sender."\n".$contact_email."\n".$info."\n".$contact_text;
  $headers = 'From: '.$contact_email;
  
  
  if (@mail($to,$subject, $body, $headers)) {
   echo 'Jūsų pranešimas sėkmingai išsiustas. ';
   
  } else {
  }  echo 'Įvyko klaida, bandykite dar karta.';
   
  } else {
   echo 'Neteisingai užpildyta forma.';
   } 
 }
?>
<form action="contact1.php" method="post">
 Pranešimas apie korupciją:<br><textarea name="contact_text" rows="6" cols="30" maxlength="1000" ></textarea><br><br>  <!--  -->
 Email (nebūtinas):<br><input type="text" name="contact_email" maxlength="30">
     <?php echo $a."+".$b."="?><input type="number" name="recaptcha" maxlength="2" style="width:40px" />
    <input type="submit" value="Siusti">
    <br>    
</form>
```

Now the problem is that I always get the message that details are incorrect. I tried to echo recaptcha just to see if $c is correct and it works. But for some reason not able to compare $recaptcha with $c or some other issue I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The value of $c will be a completely different value when the user submits the contact form vs when your validation checks it. The value will change on every request because the script is re-interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the value of $c on the initial page load, so that you can compare it afterwards in the next request. You can do that by storing it in $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
    <?php
    $min_number = 2;
    $max_number = 9;


    $random_number1 = mt_rand($min_number, $max_number);
    $random_number2 = mt_rand($min_number, $max_number);


    if (isset($_POST['contact_text']) && isset($_POST['contact_email']) ) {
        $contact_text = $_POST['contact_text'];
        $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
        $recaptcha = $_POST['recaptcha'];
        $firstNumber = $_POST["firstNumber"];
        $secondNumber = $_POST["secondNumber"];

        $checkTotal = $firstNumber + $secondNumber;


        $info = 'Pranešimas apie korupciją: ';
        $sender = 'Atsiuntė: ';

        if (!empty($contact_text) && ($recaptcha != $checkTotal ))  {

        echo $recaptcha;

        $to = 'muksinovas@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Korupcija';
        $body = $sender."\n".$contact_email."\n".$info."\n".$contact_text;
        $headers = 'From: '.$contact_email;


        if (@mail($to,$subject, $body, $headers)) {
            echo 'Jūsų pranešimas sėkmingai išsiustas. ';

        } else {
        }  echo 'Įvyko klaida, bandykite dar karta.';

        } else {
            echo 'Neteisingai užpildyta forma.';
            }   
    }
?>
<form action="contact1.php" method="post">
    Pranešimas apie korupciją:<br><textarea name="contact_text" rows="6" cols="30" maxlength="1000" ></textarea><br><br>  <!--  -->
    Email (nebūtinas):<br><input type="text" name="contact_email" maxlength="30">
    <?php
        echo $random_number1 . ' + ' . $random_number2 . ' = ';
    ?>
    <input type="number" name="recaptcha" maxlength="2" style="width:40px" />
    <input name="firstNumber" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $random_number1; ?>" />
    <input name="secondNumber" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $random_number2; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Siusti">
    <br>    
</form>
```

This might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you should to use session to solve your problem, i did little changes in your code, it should to work perfectly.

```php
<?php
    @session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['contact_text']) && isset($_POST['contact_email']) ) {

        $contact_text = $_POST['contact_text'];
        $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
        $recaptcha = $_POST['recaptcha'];

        $info = 'Pranešimas apie korupciją: ';
        $sender = 'Atsiuntė: ';

        if (!empty($contact_text) && ($recaptcha == $_SESSION["captcha"]))  {

            echo $recaptcha;

            $to = 'muksinovas@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Korupcija';
            $body = $sender."\n".$contact_email."\n".$info."\n".$contact_text;
            $headers = 'From: '.$contact_email;


            if (@mail($to,$subject, $body, $headers)) {
                echo 'Jūsų pranešimas sėkmingai išsiustas. ';

            } else {

            }  echo 'Įvyko klaida, bandykite dar karta.';

        }else{
            echo 'Neteisingai užpildyta forma.';
        }   
    }else{

        $a=rand(2,9);
        $b=rand(2,9);
        $c=$a+$b;

        //setting captcha code in session
        $_SESSION["captcha"] = $c;

        ?>
        <form action="contact1.php" method="post">
            Pranešimas apie korupciją:<br><textarea name="contact_text" rows="6" cols="30" maxlength="1000" ></textarea><br><br>  <!--  -->
            Email (nebūtinas):<br><input type="text" name="contact_email" maxlength="30">
             <?php echo $a."+".$b."="?><input type="number" name="recaptcha" maxlength="2" style="width:40px" />
            <input type="submit" value="Siusti">
            <br>    
        </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```